# How to cancel a specific alarm given that I added extra data

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am creating multiple alarms with different IDs, lets say I created alarms 1, 2,3 and I want to cancel 2 only. Can you please guide me how? I did search on the SO but  I didn't find anything about whether  I have to add the "same extra data" to pending when cancelling an alarm so I thought I would ask you and see how you would do it

Here is how  I created my alarms

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    broadcast_intent.putExtra("Tag", Object1);
    broadcast_intent.putExtra("Tag2", Object2);

   for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){       
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,  broadcast_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, pendingIntent);

   }
```

How can I cancel alarm 2?

Answer (score 0):

Its Working for me:-----

```
   buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, broadcast_intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);             
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        // Tell the user about what we did.
        Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


 }});
```

Comment: Oh so I should add the cancel current flag and I dont worry about the extra data in the intent, eh? I will try it and if works  I will accept it

Comment: It didn't work for me :( as i said something is not matching my above pending current

Comment: Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class); Initialize this globally then its working for me